# Could someone explain this question regarding asymptotes

Tags: calculus

[Asymptote http://puu.sh/rCwCy/c78a9ef78a.png](http://puu.sh/rCwCy/c78a9ef78a.png)

Well my thinking was if the asymptote is at x = 4, it will reach as close to 4 as possible but will never reach 4, meaning it's not defined at 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The techincal definition of a vertical asymptote is that $a$ is a vertical asymptote of $f$ if  $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x) = \pm\infty$ or $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x) = \pm\infty$. So you can take a simple piecewise function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-4}$ if $x\neq 4$ and $0$ if $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the function $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=4$ has absolutely nothing to do with whether $f(4)$ is defined. The function has a vertical asymptote at $x=4$ if at least one of the following four conditions is satisfied:

- $\lim\limits_{x\to 4^-}f(x)=-\infty$;
- $\lim\limits_{x\to 4^-}f(x)=+\infty$;
- $\lim\limits_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=-\infty$; or
- $\lim\limits_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=+\infty$.

Take, for instance, the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{x-4},&\text{if }x\ne 4\\
0,&\text{if }x=4\;.
\end{cases}$$

This function has a vertical asymptote at $x=4$, because $$\lim_{x\to 4^-}f(x)=-\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=+\infty\;.$$

It’s very much like the question of what the limit of some function $g(x)$ is at some point $a$: the value of $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$, if it exists at all, does not depend in the least on what $g(a)$ is, or even on whether $g(a)$ is defined at all; it’s determined by how $g(x)$ behaves as $x$ *approaches* $a$ (but is not equal to $a$). The same is true of a vertical asymptote at $a$: whether there is one depends entirely on how the function behaves as $x$ *approaches* $a$. What happens *at* $a$ is irrelevant.